# SSRS Error :Cannot access to your download link, please contact your administrator

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an issue from my ssrs export, when i use service to get data from ssrs (sql server report) and generate link to download that file there some error says "cannot access to your download link, please contact your administrator"
[Error show in chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCrui.jpg)
I don't even have clue for this issue??

when i generate directly from report server its will be generate normally

Comment: Have you tried contacting your administrator?

Comment: I didnt, I still search to fix that issue before open ticket to administrator